# can't get the format right

Tags: ruby

I have a hash that look like this

```
products = {199 =>['Shoes', 59.99], 211 =>['Shirts', 19.99], 245 =>['Hats', 25.99], 689 => ['Coats', 99.99], 712 => ['Beanies', 6.99]}
```

products = item number =>[product, price]

My goal is to print out the highest and lowest price in the hash. So far all i got is this:

```
products = {199 =>['Shoes', 59.99], 211 =>['Shirts', 19.99], 245 =>['Hats', 25.99], 689 =>['Coats', 99.99], 712 => ['Beanies', 6.99]}

max_value = products.max_by { |key, value| value[1] }.to_s
    print max_value

min_value = products.min_by { |key, value| value[1] }.to_s
     print min_value
```

When I print it out it looks like this.

```
 ["689", ["Coats", 99.99]]
["712", ["Beanies", 6.99]]
```

I would like it to look like this

```
Item# 689: Coats, 99.99
Item# 712: Beanies, 6.99
```

Does anyone have any tips for me?

I figured it out thanks to your help. Thanks much. This gives me exactly what I was looking for.

```
min_value = products.min_by { |value| value[1] }
puts "Item# #{min_value[0]}: #{min_value[1][0]}, #{min_value[1][1]}"

max_value = products.max_by { |value| value[1] }
puts "Item# #{max_value[0]}: #{max_value[1][0]}, #{max_value[1][1]}"
```

OOps, nevermind. The correct code is this

```
min_value = products.min_by { |key, value| value[1] }
puts "Item# #{min_value[0]}: #{min_value[1][0]}, $#{min_value[1][1]}"

max_value = products.max_by { |key, value| value[1] }
puts "Item# #{max_value[0]}: #{max_value[1][0]}, $#{max_value[1][1]}"
```

Comment: How do you expect it to figure out that's what you want to print? You're telling it to print an array, so that's what it does. Nowhere do you have anything about "Item#", etc. Simply pull the values you want out the the array you get and print them individually.

Comment: You can accept an answer on stack overflow by clicking on the checkbox under the vote count for an answer. This lets people know that the answer is what you are looking for and they will not duplicate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that max is the second array and min is the first:

```
puts "Min Item\# #{min[0]}: #{min[1][0]}, #{min[1][1]}"
puts "Max Item\# #{max[0]}: #{max[1][0]}, #{max[1][1]}"
```

In general, basic formatting in Ruby can be done using the string interpolation operator, `#{}` within a double quoted string. The operator replaces itself with the final value of the contained expressions after calling `to_s` on it. Ex.:

```
puts "Four plus four = #{4+4}"
```

The value of `4+4` is `8`, and `8.to_s`=`"8"`, so the string `"8"` is inserted making the final string `"Four plus four = 8"`

For mode complex formatting you will use `sprintf`, but that is a huge function that you can look into yourself.

Comment: Don't forget `min = products.min_by { |key, value| value[1] }` and the  equivalent line for max.

Comment: I know, I was just assuming that they were figured out in the same way as in the question.

Comment: Ok.  I just wanted to point it out because it's critical to remove the `to_s` on the end.

Comment: Which `to_s`? Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you sure you have to escape the # symbol?  I don't think you do, unless you are wanting to literally print "#{".

Comment: I don't know, but I do know that you can interpolate instance and globals like this: `#@someInstance` and `#$someGlobal`. I don't know whether it is necessary, but it can't do any harm.